# 3D room map of noise from outside

Tags: noise, noise-reduction

If I hear outside/street noise in the middle of room X, is there a way to perform a 3D spatial analysis of the noise?

I'd like to find tools and software to build a noise map of the room.

In the final model, the ceiling, the walls and the floor should be colored differently depending on the incoming noise flow, treating the noise as if it were light.

Can it be done ?

I bought a sound level meter on ebay and I'm waiting for delivery.

However I fear that a sound level meter is not directional enough to spot the source of the noise.

In addition, the noise is certainly echoed from the walls of the room.

How do you decide from where (door, windows, floor, walls, etc.) and in what percentage the street noise penetrates the room ?

There are vibration sensors that can be attached eg to the walls?

Thank you

Duilio

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think it can be done in the way you describe. The problem is that you cannot test the room under conditions which are controlled enough to provide useful data. If you could re-build the house inside an anechoic chamber you'd be ok ;)

I think the best idea is to define the materials of the room and then build a theoretical model of how each surface [transmits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_transmission) sound waves, then the room. You should find some data on this or could find an architect to help. Not a field I work in, but there must be some dedicated CAD type tools for this specific task.

Answer (score 0):

Just some 'random' ideas to get the debate going:

Would analysis of binaural recordings of your room be a good starting point ?

I am not an expert in signal processing but that sounds like a lead:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamforming

Charlie @Soundry

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is a so-called "reciprocal transfer path analysis" or reverse transfer path analysis:

Invert the source and the listener.

Play loud noise through a speaker, and put the speaker in different locations in your room, while recording outside on the street with a microphone how much noise is transmitted from each speaker position.
The 'leakage' works in both directions, so if you find a speaker position that results in the most sound at the mic outside, you've found the spot where most noise leaks into the room (this is under the assumption that the traffic noise outside is uniformly distributed, which it probably is).

Note that you probably need to turn up the speaker to 11 in your case to get a clear effect at the mic, especially if there is traffic during your analysis.